# Realm: update of the part RLMArray

Tags: objective-c, realm

I use Realm in my application and I have some problems with it. 
Server returns data which should be updated in my db. For example:

```
{ projects:[{ id:1, name:project1, floors:[ { id:1, name:floor1} ]  }]}
```

It says that I should update `name` and `floors` fields in project with id=1. If project from DB has `floor` with id=1, then it should be updated, otherwise should be added. But it should not delete other objects from floor array. 
What I made:

```
Project *project = [Project projectFromDictionary:dictionary];
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[Project createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithValue:project];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

But this code removes other floors in my project. What I should do?

Project class:

```
 @interface Project:RLMObject
 @property NSString *name;
 @property NSString *projectID;
 @property RLMArray<Floor *><Floor> *floors;
 @end
```

Floor:

```
 @interface Floor:RLMObject
 @property NSString *name;
 @property NSString *floorID;
 @end
 RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Floor)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`+[RLMObject createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithValue:]`](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#/c:objc%28cs%29RLMObject%28cm%29createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithValue:) or another method with the same semantics, then it will find an existing object with the same primary key and update all its properties with the new values. List properties are scanned for existing objects by primary keys and only those which are included in the provided `NSArray` remain associated with the updated `RLMObject`.

In your case, you could remove the `floors` property for each project object from your `dictionary`, so that you can still merge with said method, but merge in the floors manually yourself, by querying for each floor id on the `floors` property of your project instance, whether there is already such a floor and if not fallback to create-or-update again and associate it with the project.